# No Nuget packages found when using Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, xamarin.forms

I just installed Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 and created a Xamarin.Forms project. I'm trying to add NuGet packages to the project but nothing shows up in the Nuget Package Manager under Browse or when I search for a package. I tried to install SQLite through the Package Manager Console, but it gives an exception `Not Specified`. Any ideas how to get Nuget Packages working with Xamarin.Forms? Thanks!

Comment: Which package source are you using for your Nuget packages?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be specifically related to Xamarin.Forms, but rather an issue with the Nuget Package Manager itself Does the error contain any more information than just `Not specified`?

Comment: @CookData I've tried Nuget and Microsoft as the sources.

Comment: @Demitrian There's nothing else that I can find in the error. It works fine on a non-Xamarin Forms project

Comment: What happens when you create a new Xamarin project that is not Xamarin forms based? Also, what version of Xamarin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I fixed it by going to the package manager options and select "package sources".
I added following link to these sources and called it "Nuget":

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2

Then I selected package source: ALL (in the manager)

If you click search again, all the available packages will be visible.